# What steps should I take before staining a deck that has weathered for several months?

Tags: deck, staining

I sanded my deck last year, power washed it this year, but have not yet stained it because it won’t stop raining long enough to dry the wood for me to stain.

When and if the wood ever dries, what steps should I take before finally staining?

Comment: Try  getting a tarp remove to dry.Put on when bad storm comes.

Comment: What species of wood?

Comment: https://www.deckstainhelp.com/staining-a-new-deck/

Answer (score 2):

There's really nothing you need to do unless you're dissatisfied with the smoothness of the wood, or if it's discolored significantly and you'd like to freshen the surface. In both cases, a random-orbit sander should do a nice job of smoothing and bringing out fresh wood.